# How to get native code coverage in a mixed mode assembly in .NET 4.5.2

Tags: c++, c++-cli, code-coverage, clr

I'm working on a project in .NET 4.5.2 using C# and C++ with a C++/CLI bridge. Some of our assemblies are native C++, some are mixed C++ and C++/CLI using #pragma managed/unmanaged.

Using [OpenCppCoverage](https://github.com/OpenCppCoverage/OpenCppCoverage), I can get coverage data for our native DLLs while running our integration tests suite, but not the coverage from DLLs mixing unmanaged/managed code (managed code is covered by another tool, I only need coverage for the unmanaged part). Upon trying to cover these mixed mode DLLs, I get :

```
System.InvalidProgramException : Common Language Runtime detected an invalid program.
```

Another difficulty: the test runner (a wrapper for NUnit 2.2.6) is embedded in the host application and the tests rely on this application running and configured a certain way, so I can't easily test dlls separately (using vstest.console.exe for example). I need to use a tool that monitors and filters modules being loaded during runtime, such as OpenCppCoverage, but that can also profile the native part of mixed mode assemblies.

I know that I could isolate our native code in separate project and have the C++/CLI wrapper reference it, but I am looking for a solution that doesn't involve restructuring our whole solution.

Thanks

Comment: Seems like you ask a very specialized question, with restrictions on the calling site. I have a mixed-mode assembly with 2 .Net assemblies, that are tested by three different assemblies (managed, mixed, native) and I can cover the Code with Resharper Ultimate. But don't know if that helps

Comment: Hi, thanks the answer. I was using the standalone dotCover console tool. I tried the ReSharper Ultimate trial version, but it doesn't seem to work any different than the console tool. Seems like they're about to add better support though: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSCPP-13781#

Comment: Ok, i checked another project, and it does not list and cover unmanaged dlls. My first check was special as I got plenty of test but only a mixed assembly. But there is was definitely working.